# Card view is not visible

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, visible, android-cardview

I am trying to add card view with recycler view. But it is not showing anything, just a blank view.

I have seen questions for this here, it has answers to add dependencies for recycler view and card view. This is present in my gradle. Another is to use getItemCount like this:

```
 @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mImage.length;
    }
```

This is also I think is right I have used list.size();
I am not getting what's going on. I want to retrieve the data from database , may be that's going wrong. Can anyone help please.

TableListAdapter

```
    public class TableListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TableListAdapter.TableViewHolder> {

    TimeTableHelper db;

    private List<TimeTable> List;

    public TableListAdapter(List<TimeTable> List) {
            this.List = List;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
          return List.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TableViewHolder contactViewHolder, int i) {

        TimeTable table = db.getTables(i);
        TimeTable ci = List.get(i);
        contactViewHolder.tableTitle.setText(table.getTitle());
   }

   @Override
   public TableViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                    from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                    inflate(R.layout.table_card, viewGroup, false);

        return new TableViewHolder(itemView);
   }

  public static class TableViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

      protected TextView tableTitle;
      protected CardView cv;
      protected Switch aSwitch;


      public TableViewHolder(View v) {
          super(v);
          tableTitle =  (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tableTitle);
          cv = (CardView)  v.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
          aSwitch = (Switch)  v.findViewById(R.id.switch2);
      }
  }
}
```

TimeTableList Activity

```
public class TimeTableList extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public ArrayList<TimeTable> items;
    public TableListAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_time_table_list);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Time Table");
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_24dp);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        items=new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        initRecyclerAdapter();

        ImageButton fab = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NewTimeTable.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    private void initRecyclerAdapter() {
        adapter = new TableListAdapter(items);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

list xml layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout.activities.TimeTableList">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:id="@+id/view5">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view5" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end">

        <include layout="@layout/myfab"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

table_card xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:measureWithLargestChild="false">
    <!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                android:id="@+id/tableTitle" />

            <Switch
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/switch2"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.3.0'
}
```

TimeTableHelper:

```
    public class TimeTableHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


    private static final String TABLE_TIME_TABLE = "timetables";
    private static final String KEY_TABLE_TITLE = "tabletitle";
    private static final String KEY_STATUS = "status";
    private static final String KEY_TABLE_ID = "tableid";
    private static final String KEY_TABLE_COLOR = "tablecolor";

    public TimeTableHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, Constants.DATABASE_NAME, null, Constants.DATABASE_VERSION);

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TIME_TABLE);

        // createTable(db);
        // onCreate(db);
    }
    public void addTimeTable(TimeTable table) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_TABLE_TITLE, table.getTitle());
        values.put(KEY_STATUS, table.getStatus());
        values.put(KEY_TABLE_COLOR, table.getTableColor());

        db.insert(TABLE_TIME_TABLE, null, values);

        db.close();
    }

    public TimeTable getTables(int id) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_TIME_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_TABLE_ID,
                        KEY_TABLE_TITLE, KEY_TABLE_COLOR ,KEY_STATUS}, KEY_TABLE_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        TimeTable table = new TimeTable(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)),Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)));

        return table;

    }

    public List<TimeTable> getAllTables() {
        List<TimeTable> conList = new ArrayList<TimeTable>();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TIME_TABLE;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                TimeTable table = new TimeTable();

                table.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                table.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
                table.setStatus(cursor.getInt(2));
                table.setTableColor(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)));

                conList.add(table);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return conList;
    }
}
```

create table:

```
  String CREATE_TIME_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TIME_TABLE + "("
            + KEY_TABLE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + KEY_TABLE_TITLE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_STATUS + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_TABLE_COLOR + " TEXT" + ")";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_TIME_TABLE);
```

Thank you..

Comment: `private List<TimeTable> List;` just a slight OCD problem from my side, but please do not use Pascal case naming for variable names, only class names should have names starting with Capital letter

Comment: In `onCreateViewHolder()` you are inflating `R.layout.table_card` , but you have posted `card.xml` 's code here, can you post the code of `table_card.xml` file here too

Comment: It's table_card only. Sorry i'll edit the name.@Bhargav

Comment: changed list name..same issue.

Comment: instead of `Switch` try using `android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat`

Comment: Also why are you doing this `recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);` ?

Comment: Also you have initialized items `items=new ArrayList<>();` where exactly are you adding elements to it? `items.add()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not added content in your list as i can see in your code, thats why its showing blank because list size is **ZERO** at that time.

You just initialize your list and set the adapter. Add some data in your list before initializing adapter.

> Your code

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        items=new ArrayList<>();   // **Add data to list after initialization**
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        initRecyclerAdapter();

        ImageButton fab = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NewTimeTable.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I changed this   timeTableHelper = new TimeTableHelper(this);
        items=new ArrayList<TimeTable>(timeTableHelper.getAllTables());  ,,,, and worked... Than you..@Anuj Sharma

Comment: Cheers !! Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 2):

From your code what I can see is your forgot to add data points to the `items` variable

Just change your activity code to this, here the change I have done is added the function given by @VaibhavSinghal to update your recycler view adapter, then call it by passing the list you get from TimeTableHelper.getAllTables()

```
public class TimeTableList extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public ArrayList<TimeTable> items;
    public TableListAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_time_table_list);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Time Table");
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_24dp);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        items=new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        initRecyclerAdapter();
        // Get reference to your time tableHelper
        TimeTableHelper timeTableHelper = new TimeTableHelper(this);
        // Update your adapter with elements returned by getAllTables() function
        updateAdapterList(timeTableHelper.getAllTables());

        ImageButton fab = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NewTimeTable.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    private void initRecyclerAdapter() {
        adapter = new TableListAdapter(items);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void updateAdapaterList(List<TimeTable> newTimeTableList) {   
        //Replace the current list with new list
        this.List = newTimeTableList;
        //notify the adapter that the data set has changed
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you to you too.. Summed up all answers and worked.. :-) @Bhargav

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, you are passing an empty list into the `TableListAdapter` in `TimeTableList` (activity).
As the list size is `0` during the creation of the Adapter, there are not going to be any cardViews created for the RecyclerView.

Either you should **add some data points into the list before creating the instance** of the `TableListAdapter`

**OR**

Have a **public void updateRecyclerAdapter(List itemList)** in `TableListAdapter` that you can call post creating the instance of the adapter.
The method can possibly look something like below code

```
public void updateAdapaterList(List<TimeTable> newTimeTableList) {   
    //Replace the current list with new list
    this.List = newTimeTableList;
    //notify the adapter that the data set has changed
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**ALSO**

make sure you override the `getItemCount()` method in the RecyclerAdapter as below.

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return List.size();
}
```

Also I would highly recommend using proper *camelCasing* while coding. :)

Comment: I tried using updateRecyclerAdapter but did not work..@Vaibhav Singhal

Comment: Have you overriden the getItemCount() method to return the size of the timeTableList ?

Comment: yes I have did..     @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
          return tableList.size();
    }

Comment: I got the list using this: timeTableHelper = new TimeTableHelper(this); items=new ArrayList<TimeTable>(timeTableHelper.getAllTables());

Comment: But now its not getting update if I add the  table and come back to the activity. I tried this update method but in that it dose not resolve notifyDataSetChanged() method.

Comment: Cool. I was going to ask you to update your activity code. Glad it's working.